# Spring profile not working in logback configuration

Tags: java, spring, logback, spring-profiles

I configured logback,
but it always uses my local profile,
even when I set `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`.
Has anyone solved this issue?
Here is a code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
   <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
   <springProfile name="local">
      <include resource="logging/logback-local.xml"/>
   </springProfile>
   <springProfile name="dev">
      <!--Console Appender-->
      <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
         <target>System.out</target>
         <encoder>
            <Pattern>
               %-5level [%thread] %class \(%file:%line\) - %m%n
            </Pattern>
         </encoder>
      </appender>
      <!--File Appender-->
      <include resource="logging/appenders/rolling-file-appender.xml"/>
      <!--Logger for springframework-->
      <logger name="org.springframework" level="debug" additivity="false">
         <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      </logger>
      <logger name="httpclient.wire" level="debug" additivity="false">
         <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      </logger>
      <!--Logger for all of Blah-->
      <logger name="com.blah" level="debug" additivity="false">
         <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
      </logger>
      <!--Logger for test package-->
      <logger name="com.blah.test" level="debug" additivity="false">
         <appender-ref ref="FILE-APPENDER"/>
      </logger>
      <!--Root logger-->
      <root level="debug" additivity="false">
         <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" additivity="false"/>
      </root>
   </springProfile>
```

Comment: Have you set your logback file within `src/main/resources`? Btw, have you named your logback file `logback-spring.xml`? In addition, I think you don't need to include those includes... just remove them. Also, how are you starting up your application?

Comment: Please read again your question (then edit and clarify)

Comment: if you change the `<springProfile name="local">`  to `<springProfile name="local2">` does it gives the same result? if it is, then maybe the problem could be in `<include resource` part

Comment: It seems my configuration was correct all along. The issue was there was a configuration in our build.gradle for bootRun that was always setting spring.profiles.active=local. Why? I have no clue.